# passing a variable through urls.py django

Tags: django, variables, hyperlink, django-urls

I want to pass a string in a url (like a get request). The point is to get the file requested, and download it.
I was just wondering what the urls.py file would look like?
I put this, but it is forcing me to put the entire path (like /download/home/......./file/) in the url.

```
(r'^download(?P<name>.*)$', upload_view.download)
```

I just want to put /download/file in the url

Comment: What does your requirements document look like?

Comment: what do u mean by requirements document?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in your urls.py, but in your view code.  You will need to process your filename by adding the root path to it.